# Devise: I can't display only current user workouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I created little sport app and now I have problem with show only current user workouts on index page.

**The problem :** *NoMethodError in WorkoutsController#index. undefined method `workouts' for nil:NilClass.*

```
def index
    @workouts = current_user.workouts.all
end
```

**I leave all details below:**

*Associations*

1. In my User model I have

   **has_many :workouts**
2. In my Workout model I wrote

   **belongs_to :user**
3. In my views/workouts/index.html.erb

   ```
   <% @workouts.each do |workout| %>
       <h4><%= link_to workout.date, workout %></h4>
       <h3><%= workout.workout %></h3>
   <% end %>
   ```

Comment: Did you miss adding `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in your controller?

Comment: it means that current_user is nil(you have not logged in)

Comment: The relation seems to be ok. Inspect current_user. try inspecting using puts current_user.inspect. check what it gives, that must be null

Comment: In my workout controller I have -> before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
def index
    @workouts = current_user.present? ? current_user.workouts : []
end
```

i think there is error when you are not loged, and `current_user`  return nil

Comment: Better use before_filter :authenticate_user! to prevent this exception

Comment: when you use :authenticate_user! you wil lose access to `index` for not logged user ...

Comment: if you read the question you will see that workout belongs to user. and could not be displayed without user.

Comment: It works fine. Thanks for your answer. For better understanding can you describe how exactly this code work for me?

Comment: Yea, `current_user.present? ?` check if user is logged, if yes, it returns `current_user.workouts`, if not, it returns empty array

Comment: It was nice idea. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of workouts for current_user than current_user should be defined. It means you need to log in. You can check it easily with before filter

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

and after you use your code

```
@workouts = current_user.workouts.all
```

if you want to show workouts of another users you can skip the filter for new action

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:another_index]

  def another_index
    @workouts = User.find(params[:id]).workouts.all
  end

end
```

Comment: I had in my workouts controller -> before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]. It was frustrating because I made similar displaying only current user posts in my other projects, but I was struggle with this app. Gladis code works for me. Thanks for all answers. Have a nice day.